# Modify this yup validation to change max length to 9 if the string does not include a dash

Tags: regex, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I'm trying to write a yup validator that validates a field's max length, depending on whether a dash is included in the string.  If a dash is included, the max length is 10, if there is no dash, the max length should be 9.

For example:

`'string-111'` should have a max length of 10.

`'string111'` should have a max length of 9.

My current code looks like:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export default Yup.object().shape({
  description: Yup.string()
    .matches(
      /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/,
      'Invoice # can only contain letters, numbers and dashes'
    )
    .max(10, 'Invoice # has a max length of 10 characters'),
});
```

I see the yup documentation https://github.com/jquense/yup has a `.when()` method, but it seems to be used in very specific cases in their examples.  Here, the user can place the dash anywhere in the string.

Any ideas on how to rewrite this validator, so that when there is no dash in the string, the maxlength should be 9?

Comment: Do you mean like `^[a-z]{6}-?[0-9]{3}$` with an optional hyphen and only chars a-z before and 3 digits at the end? https://regex101.com/r/NqiHSZ/1

Comment: No, those were just examples, the dash can come anywhere, its not restricted it to a position.  the max length should change to 9 if there is no dash included in the string the user enters.

Comment: Can the dash be at the start or at the end as well?

Comment: Yes it can (as odd as that sounds, the business is allowing it)

Comment: You could match either 9 chars `[a-z0-9]` or match 10 chars with a single hyphen  `^(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{10}$)[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9]{9})$`  https://regex101.com/r/eUG3GG/1

Answer (score 2):

You could match either match 10 chars where a hyphen can occur at any place using a positive lookahad,  or match 9 chars consisting only of a-z0-9.

```
^(?:(?=[a-z0-9-]{10}$)[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9]{9})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

    - `[a-z0-9-]{10}$` Match 10 times either a-z0-9 or - till the end of the string
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*` Match a hyphen between chars a-z0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-z0-9]{9}` Match 9 chars a-z0-9
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUG3GG/1/)

Comment: I'll try it out, this is some good regex but its not really covering the issue im trying to solve.  I was looking for more of an implementation with yup validations but i'll give this a shot and see if it works the way im hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

I worked up a solution I liked but found it had already been posted by @Thefourthbird, so I tried a different tack and came up with this:

```
/^(?=(?:-*[^-]-*){9}$)(?=(?:[^-]*-[^-]*){0,1}$).*/gm
```

You can see that this regex contains two *positive lookaheads*, both beginning at the start of a line. The first  ensures that the string contains 9 non-hyphens; the second requires that there be at most one hyphen.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vc29tj/1/)

The demo provides a detailed and thorough explanation of how this regex works, but we can also make it self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
/
^                      # match beginning of string
(?=                    # begin a positive lookahead
  (?:-*[^-]-*){9}      # match 9 strings, each with one char that is
                       # not a hyphen, possibly preceded and/or
                       # followed by hyphens
  $                    # match the end of a line
)                      # end positive lookahead

(?=                    # begin a positive lookahead
  (?:[^-]*-[^-]*){0,1} # match 0 or 1 strings, each containing one hyphen, 
                       # possibly preceded and/or followed by non-hyphens
  $                    # match the end of the string
)                      # end positive lookahead

.*                     # match 0+ characters (the entire string)
/gmx                   # global, multiline and free-spacing regex
                       # definition modes
```

If desired, `[^-]` could replaced with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, `\p{Alnum}` or something else, depending on requirements.

Comment: @Poul, I agree, and began working on one right after I posted.

Comment: Thanks, these are good regex functions, as mentioned to @Thefourthbird, its not the regex that my question is focused on, its the yup validation with the .when() method.  These are good for the regex, I'll try both solutions in a bit but the way the validation for this app should work is with using yup validations and im assuming the .when() method.

Comment: ghostly agent, I noticed a similar comment you left on 4th bird's answer, but since I know nothing of yup, but the required regex is non-trivial, I thought it might be of help, especially if you find a yup expert who is regex-challenged.